# Use the graph api to access a user's public photos without them granting authentication

Tags: facebook-graph-api, public, photos

Is it possible to get a specific user's public photos without them authenticating the app, I can view them from within facebook but it seems I can't from site, is that right? and does anyone know why?

this album for example: http://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.10150158918052693.289402.722802692&type=3 can be viewed on facebook

but the graph explorer returns false here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=10150158918052693

Answer (score 0):

From Facebook photo documentation

> any valid access_token if it is public and owned by the Page. [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo)

So grab an access token for the app, then just do something like this...

```
SELECT
  object_id
FROM photo
WHERE owner={user_id}
```

Comment: But User Page is different from Public Page